# Solidity: how to initialise a fix array from a single value?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to pass a single parameter as array into a function call:

```
contract MyToken is StandaloneERC20 {

    function initialize(
        address owner,
        address minter,
        address[] memory pausers
    ) public initializer {

        address[] memory minters = [minter];

        StandaloneERC20.initialize("MyToken", "MTK", uint8(18), minters, pausers);
    }
```

`StandaloneERC20.initialize` expects an array for the forth argument `minters`:

```
function initialize(
    string memory name, string memory symbol, uint8 decimals, address[] memory minters, address[] memory pausers
) public initializer {
```

However, using my code I get the following compiler error with solidity 0.5.7:

```
TypeError: Type address[1] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] memory.

    address[] memory minters = [minter];
    ^---------------------------------^
```

I have also tried to pass the minter as array-argument:

```
contract MyToken is StandaloneERC20 {

    function initialize(
        address owner,
        address minter,
        address[] memory pausers
    ) public initializer {

        StandaloneERC20.initialize("MyToken", "MTK", uint8(18), [minter], pausers);
    }
```

But this seems to be completely different from what I would expect because of this compiler error:

```
Member "initialize" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract StandaloneERC20).
        StandaloneERC20.initialize("MyToken", "MT", uint8(18), [minter], pausers);
        ^------------------------^
```

How can I pass a single argument as array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way to declare an array with single argument

```
contract MyToken is StandaloneERC20 {
    function initialize(
        address owner, 
        address minter, 
        address[] memory pausers
    ) public initializer {
        address[] memory minters = new address[](1);
        minters[0] = minter;
        StandaloneERC20.initialize("MyToken", "MTK", uint8(18), minters, pausers);
    }
}
```

Here is `Solidity` docs about [Allocating Memory Arrays](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html?highlight=array#allocating-memory-arrays)